# How to capture field value when a method of a class is called in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a weird 3rd party library that requires me doing the following (`A` is imported from that library):

```
def foo(my_props):
  a = A()
  a.props = my_props
  a.post()
```

So what I want is to make sure that when `a.post()` is called, its `props` are set correctly. Note that this is a greatly simplified example so it's apparent it would be easy to mock `foo` instead. Unfortunately there is much more into it (like `my_props` may be modified in `foo` before calling `a.post`).

Worth noting that from looking into the source code of that import, `props` is not a class property. It's a simple `dict`, class field, set something like `self.props = ...` at random places in the class `A`.

So how can I setup my mocking to accomplish this feast? I am not even interested in `post` itself. I need to know how many times `delete` is called and what values `props` were set at that time.

**EDIT**: re-enforcing @hspandher response, ended up doing the following because unfortunately `call_args` stayed empty, which I hoped I could have analyzed after the call.

```
@mock.patch('A.props', return_value=mock.PropertyMock())
def test_foo(self, mock_props):
    call_args = []
    def capture(*args, **kwargs):
        call_args.append(args)

    mock_props.__set__ = functools.partial(capture)

    a = A()
    a.foo()

    # analyze call_args...
```

Comment: Mock `A` itself, so that you can examine the value of `A.__call__.return_value` (which is a mock itself standing in for `a`) after `foo` returns. If `A` can be instantiated multiple times, you'll have to do a little more work to distinguish between various "fake" instances of `A`.

Comment: can you initialize `a` before `foo` and pass as argument?  i.e. `a = A(); def foo(my_props, a):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you don't even need mocking, lets say foo is defined in file code.py, in test file code should be like this `from code import A       A.props = <mockvalue>` and then your testing code. But if you to want to do something little more sophisticated like mocking post , I suggest you use python mock or fudge library

Comment: This what seems worked for me. Decorate the method with ` @mock.patch('FuelSDK.ET_DataExtension_Row.props', return_value=mock.PropertyMock())`. Capture the setter: `mock_props.__set__ = functools.partial(capture)`. Analyze input to `capture` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you can initialize `a` outside of `foo` and pass as argument so the actual call looks like this:

```
def foo(my_props, obj):
    obj.props = my_props
    obj.post()

foo({'bar': 'baz'}, a)
```

Then you could test it like this:

```
def test_foo():
    a = mock.create_autospec(A)
    foo(1, a)
    assert a.props == 1
    assert a.mock_calls == [mock.call.post()]
```

Checking if `props` are set before calling `post` is a little more work.
You will need to convert `foo` to a class `Foo`:

```
class Foo(object):

    def foo(self, my_props, obj):
        self._setup_props(my_props, obj)
        self._post(obj)

    def _setup_props(self, my_props, obj):
        obj.props = my_props

    def _post(self, obj):
        obj.post()
```

Now you can mock `Foo` itself and it's `foo` method to check the `mock_calls` order:

```
>>> f = mock.Mock(spec=Foo, foo=Foo.foo)
>>> f.foo(f, 1, 2)
>>> f.mock_calls
[call._setup_props(1, 2), call._post(2)]
```